# React:Do I make one line html as component or not?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Suppose I have one p tag which is used(with different class) so many times in web pages. So should I make it component or not?

If I make it component, then in future if I have to wrapped it inside suppose div tag then I only have to make changes as one place, otherwise I have to change it at every place.

Suppose I have 50 p tag in my parent component and if I make p tag component and use at wherever needed, then for all 50 time it will call that component(p tag component) which can be avoid if directly use p tag(which is I guess good for performance compare to former one).

Comment: you could make it as a functional component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the project and your uses. In general, there is no reason to wrap native elements into a component.

What do you want to achieve by having a paragraph component? If it's different classes on every P tag, why not pass down a prop from the parent component into the wrapper of the P tag, and in the P tag you can do something like:

```
<p className={this.props.className + "-specialParagraph"}>Foo</p>
```

That way, you can have a special class for every P tag without making an actual component out of it.

But as I said, it really depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to wrap native DOM elements inside React components. Just use them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create the component, so you can change it without going through the whole project. You can also wrap the logic for that piece of code, furthermore, you can test it.